# I have a class that I am trying to toggle on but it is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I am trying to toggle a class onto one of my divs when I click on a button and for some reason the class will be added to the div but the actual CSS properties do not happen. The function that I am trying to run is at the bottom.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="mainPage">
   <form class="homeButton" action="">
      <input type="submit" value="Click to see who has had a worse day!">
   </form>
</div>
<div class="textBox">
   <h3>On (fill date), this person had a really terrible day.</h3>
   <div class="badEvent">
      <p>
      </p>
   </div>
   <button>Close</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mainPage {
   background-color: #043D5D;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   h2 {
      font-size: 4em;
   }
   p {
      font-size: 2em;
   }
   form {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      input {
         width: 350px;
         height: 50px;
         border-radius: 10px;
         font-size: .95em;
         border: 1px solid #EB5055;
         background-color: #EB5055;
         cursor: pointer;
      }
   }
}


.replace {
   background-color: red;
}
```

JS

```
$(".homeButton").on("click", function(event){

   event.preventDefault();
   $(".textBox").toggleClass('.replace');

});
```

Comment: can you provide your html markup?

Comment: Sorry I add an issue posting the question.  The html markup should be there now @bencripps.

Comment: for one thing, you need to add event as an `argument` to your anonymous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, with the statement:

```
$(".textBox").toggleClass('.replace');
```

you are actually toggling the class `.replace` and not `replace`. The `.` is only for querying process. The class name is still `replace` only. So, change to

```
$(".textBox").toggleClass('replace');
```

and the code [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ufwj9g/).

Answer (score 0):

Is that the entire stylesheet or did you cut it off for brevity?  If it's not cut off, check the last bracket that seems to be missing after .replace and remove the period from the toggleClass.

```
$(".textBox").toggleClass('replace');
```

Comment: I cut it out of a longer style sheet and missed copying that.  I have updated the question now.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: damn it hjpotter92 beat me to it while editing, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
$(".homeButton").on("click", function(event){ // add event inside the brackets
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".textBox").toggleClass('replace'); // remove the . from ('.replace')
});
```

Change `.replace` to `replace` since you are already toggling a class.

In the *click* function add an `event` parameter since you are using `event.preventDefault();`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rda06uh0/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your class `.homeButton` must be on your button, not in your form tag. Also, if you are not sending the form it's better just to use an anchor tag or a button tag without the form.